# Why resize: both does not work on fieldset?

Tags: html, css

Why does it not enable resize control on the fieldset?

Docs only say that

> resize does not apply to the following:
>
> - Inline elements
> - Block elements for which the overflow property is set to visible

```css
fieldset {
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend>Controls</legend>
  <label>Input: </label><input type="number" value="20"/>
</fieldset>
```

I tried wrapping fieldset in a div and also wrapping everything in fieldset with a div and made that resizeable. That kind of works but the drag handle is many pixels off the fieldset border. Also when resizing it looks weird and sometimes hides the fieldset borders.

Comment: because the devs behind html css are damn bad.
And is just the top of the iceberg.

Answer (score 0):

Check this, it may help you.

> There are several special styling considerations for .
>
> Its display value is block by default, and it establishes a block
> formatting context. If the  is styled with an inline-level
> display value, it will behave as inline-block, otherwise it will
> behave as block. By default there is a 2px groove border surrounding
> the contents, and a small amount of default padding. The element has
> min-inline-size: min-content by default.
>
> If a `<legend>` is present, it is placed over the block-start border.
> The  shrink-wraps, and also establishes a formatting context.
> The display value is blockified. (For example, display: inline behaves
> as block.)
>
> There will be an anonymous box holding the contents of the `<fieldset>`,
> which inherits certain properties from the `<fieldset>`. If the
>
> is styled with display: grid or display: inline-grid, then
> the anonymous box will be a grid formatting context. If the ``
> is styled with display: flex or display: inline-flex, then the
> anonymous box will be a flex formatting context. Otherwise, it
> establishes a block formatting context.
>
> You can feel free to style the `<fieldset>` and `<legend>` in any way you
> want to suit your page design.

src: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset#styling_with_css)

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing). Use blockquote formatting for all text you are quoting -- you can use the button whose icon resembles `"` (except curly). Also, you'll need to enclose HTML tags with tick marks to mark them as code. See [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for more info.

Comment: This still does not answer the question. Can you please explain more what's stopping it from using `resize`?